# Transform string "3,55" to "3.55" java

Tags: java, string, text, double

I'm making a calculator in javafx with eclipse.
So i use a double type to calculate.
I want to transform a string result like : "3,55" to "3.55" because i need to use Double.parseDouble(result);

And if i put "3,55" into Double.parseDouble(result); 
it gives me an error like :
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3,5".

How to transform it ?

Comment: `string.replace(",", ".")`

Comment: it don't works :/
Edit : Nvm, it works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your value is in `String value = "3,22"` you should call `value.replace()` and pass the replace function two arguments. First argument is the argument that should be find and replaced with the second argument. `replace()` returns the string in which first passed argument is replaced with second argument.

```
String value = "3,22";
String replacedValue = value.replace(",",".");
```

Parsing the replacedValue to double or Integer should not throw exception. The `NumberFormatException` is because of the comma. See a sample test below:

```
public class Sample{ 
         public static void main(String []args){
            String value = "3,22"; 
            Double d = Double.parseDouble(value.replace(",",".")); 
            System.out.println(d); 
         }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you again Raf ! i found it :)

Comment: Glad it helped, provided more explanation on how the String's replace() method work.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to use `replace`:

```
String str = "3,55";
str = str.replace(',', '.');
```